# Jest & Supertest - Response is not populate

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have written a following test case using jest to test REST API:

```
test('Should return module for given module name' , async () =>{
const response = await request(app)
.get('/modules')
.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +User1.tokens[0].token)
.send('modulename','Shark')
.expect(200)
expect(response.body.name[0]).toBe('Shark')
```

Corresponding node js route is

```
   var modulename = req.query.modulename;
   console.log(modulename)
   const modules = await LuaModule.findByName(modulename)
   res.send(modules)
}
```

.expect(200) succeeds however expect(response.body.name).toBe('Shark') fails even though API returns JSON response having 'name' field with value as 'Shark'. Jest throws following error:

Expected: Shark 
Received: undefined

Server-Side Route-handler:

```
router.get('/modules', auth, async(req, res) => {
    var modulename = req.query.modulename;
    console.log(modulename);
    const modules = await LuaModule.findByName(modulename);
    res.send(modules);
}
```

Any suggestion regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: Can you verify that `/modules` is a GET-route?

Comment: yes, it is. Infact .expect(200) returns true.

Comment: Can you please add your nodejs route handler as well?

Comment: ``` router.get('/modules', auth, async (req,res)=>{
    var modulename = req.query.modulename;
    console.log(modulename)
    const modules = await LuaModule.findByName(modulename)
    res.send(modules)
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're expecting a query parameter to be set in the request on the server side, you need to make sure it's set correctly by `supertest`:

```
const response = await request(app)
.get('/modules')
.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +User1.tokens[0].token)
.query({modulename: 'Shark'}); // instead of .send(...)
...
```

Also since you're returning an **array** (and **not** an object) you need to access the name property of the object at the first index as:

```
expect(response.body[0].name).toBe('Shark')
```

Comment: What is actually being returned from your `LuaModule.findByName(modulename)`? Can you `console.log()` it?

Comment: Can you log what is actually returned by the `LuaModule.findByName(modulename)` call., please?

Comment: `[
    {
        "_id": "5ecfbac410555312bc4fbbe9",
        "name": "Shark",
        "environment": "Apple",
        "description": "Description",
        "owner": "5ecfbac210555312bc4fbbcc",
        "modulefile": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
 
            ]
        },
        "createdAt": "2020-05-28T13:21:08.037Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-05-28T13:21:08.037Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]`

Comment: Well that explains it ... you're returning an array not an object! I've edited my anser ;)

Comment: thanks. it worked. i was using ` response.body.name[0] `

Comment: Great, happy to help :)